# How to subtract this time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two timestamps (please see below) of format hh:mm:ss.000. I need to find out the time difference between two timestamps including milliseconds. Pleas help.

column1   (20:47:39.891)      column2 (20:47:39.755)

I have 10000 columns this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but, Excel time values are expressed in days. Just multiply the result by 86400 (number of seconds in a day). So, 86400 *(20:47:39.891 - 20:47:39.755) = 0.136 seconds of difference.